# How does eventlistener work in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

From using `querySelector`, querying a form element and adding an event listener to the latter, I want to understand how the submit button is involved. Is it because the submit button is what gives meaning to the form? And please provide me with some good resources on JavaScript and DOM scripting. Thanks and regards.

```js
// const taskInput = document.getElementById('task');
// const heading = document.querySelector('h5');

function handleEvent(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const { type, target } = evt;
  console.log({ type, target });
}
const form = document.querySelector('form');

// submit
form.addEventListener('submit', handleEvent);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div id="main" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
          <div class="row">
            <form id="task-form">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="Walk the dog">
                <label for="task">New Task</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
          <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, it isn't. it's binding the submit event handler to the form.

Comment: The submit button will trigger a `submit` event on the form. Forms might be submitted in multiple ways, for example, programmatically which will still trigger a `submit` event even if the button isn't pressed.

Comment: though... it's important to note that calling form.submit() will *not* trigger the submit event.

Comment: You can read about it here: [HTMLFormElement: submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)